# AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery header value "RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to authorize a cloud provider following [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/anti-request-forgery/sample/MvcSample/Startup.cs) on localhost, in ConfigureServices method, my Startup.cs file has

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken");
```

Inside a [HttpGet] controller method, I am trying to validate the request with:

```
await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext);
```

This is throwing the exception. Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

GET method should not change any data, so it is considered as a safe method and there is no need to protect this method from CSFR. You can see from the example, only [POST method](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/3fece4e2869581df72090ff5e82af1a09d927699/aspnetcore/security/anti-request-forgery/sample/MvcSample/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L32) is protected.
Your browser sends GET request to your site without additional anti forgery header, that is why the exception is thrown.